# Lightning DateTimePicker is using wrong icons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datetime, style

[image]

It is currently showing the icons above, instead of datetime lightning icons.
How can we correct this?

we are using ui:datetimepicker like below:

```
<ui:inputDateTime class="slds-input form-control" value="{!v.Field.FieldValue}" displayDatePicker="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
input__icon slds-input__icon--right slds-button slds-button--icon" tabindex="-1">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:event" size="x-small" class="slds-button__icon" />
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Calendar</span>
                </button>
```

It gives you the following
[image]